# Converting a polymorphic database row into the corresponding Eloquent model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, polymorphism

I might be using the wrong terminology here, which I apologise for in advance!

I've got an existing database table which looks like..

Events:

| id | type | title | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PARTY | Summer party | 2023-08-01 |
| 2 | HOLIDAY | Christmas | 2023-12-25 |

I've got a parent Eloquent model called `Event` and then `Holiday` and `Party`.

Each child model extends the `Event` and applies a scope e.g.

```php
static::addGlobalScope('type', function (Builder $builder) {
    $builder->where('type', 'PARTY');
});
```

This way we can do `Holiday::all()` and `Party::all()` and we'll get filtered results as a Collection of `Party` or `Holiday` models/classes expected.

Each child model has its own unique functions e.g. `$party->dance()`

Users can attend events which can be retrieved by calling `$user->events` which is just a HasMany:

```php
public function events(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}
```

However when we call `$user->events` because the HasMany returns Event models, we lose our OOP stuff on each model.

Is there a way to morph the models as they're returned based on their types? So instead of getting a collection of `Event` we get a `Party` and a `Holiday` model back in the collection? The end result should look something like this:

```
$results = Collection([
   Party([id: 1, title: Summer Party, date: XXXX, type: PARTY])
   Holiday([id: 2, title: Christmas, date: XXXX, type: HOLIDAY])
])
```

Thanks

Comment: How does `$user->events()` work since there is no `events.user_id` field?

Comment: I think thats irrelevent, all the above code is pseudo written in a way to focus the issue on how to resolve the correct model from the container

Comment: Well, when one doesn't know how to solve the issue, they are not supposed to presume what is irrelevant and what not but rather provide answer if helper needs it (help to be helped), usually. But good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your relations like the following

```
public function events(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class)->where('type', 'PARTY');
}
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't solving the issue at all - events SHOULD come back with a mixture of types, however the model that it returns needs to be resolved based off the type.